# Calculate the volume of a tetrahedron with vertices $(1,1,1)$, $(2,1,1)$, $(1,2,1)$, $(1,1,2)$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, 3d, volume

Calculate the volume of a tetrahedron whose vertices are $(1,1,1),(2,1,1),(1,2,1),(1,1,2)$.

I don't know how to start, do I have to find the planes?

Comment: This is not a trivial problem. See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/979/algorithm-for-finding-the-volume-of-a-convex-polytope)

Comment: Finding the equations of the planes looks like a useful way to start this particular problem.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1734604/find-the-volume-of-the-tetrahedron-using-triple-integrals may help you.

Comment: When trying to find a volume (or some other metric) of a region via integration, the bounds of the integrals come from the boundary equations. So yes, you should start by finding the equations of the bounding planes. (Fortunately they're not too hard in this case)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/922879/help-evaluating-triple-integral-over-tetrahedron is almost exactly what you want.

Comment: Anything to say about the answer or the comments, Haitian?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Shift the tetrahedron by $(-1, -1, -1)$ then the vertices becomes

$(0,0,0), (1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1) $

So the volume is one third the area of the base times the height, which

$$
V = \frac{1}{3} \left( \dfrac{1}{2} (1)^2 \right) (1) = \dfrac{1}{6}
$$

And we're done.

However, if you want to calculate the volume using integration, then you can use

$V = \displaystyle \int_{z=0}^1 A(z) \ dz $

where $A(z) $ is the cross sectional area of the tetrahedron at elevation $z$.  Using similar triangles, or vector methods, one can show that the cross-section area is given by

$A(z) = A(0) (1 - z)^2  = \dfrac{1}{2} (1 - z)^2$

Hence, the volume is

$ V = \displaystyle \int_0^1 \dfrac{1}{2} (1 - z)^2 = \dfrac{1}{6} $

Comment: That's good – but, given the tags, I suspect OP wants a solution using Calculus.

Comment: Do mention the scalar triple product ogf the edge vectors.

Comment: good, but I was thinking dping it with a triple integration

Comment: @HaitianSpaceman Details like that are important and should be part of the question text. You can edit the question to fix that.

Comment: Check the link in the comments above by @GerryMyerson